# Action bar item not finding the id

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm following the `Adding Action Button` tutorial on `devolper.android.com` and I've ran into yet another problem. When I go to reference the action bar id with `R.id.action_search` it says it doesnt exist, but `R.id.action_settings` shows up just fine...?

onOptionsItemSelected method:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    //int id = item.getItemId();
    //if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        //return true;
    //}
    //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        openSearch();
        return true;

    case R.id.action_settings:
        openSettings();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

main.xml:

```
<menu>
<!--  Search should appear as an action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"   />

<!-- Settings should appear as an action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never"    />
</menu>
```

Comment: well, the id says it's actually "action_sear"

Comment: Try "case R.id.action_sear:"

Comment: @TomislavNovoselec I must have copied that wrong cause it's actually `action_search` in my code, whoops lol I'll update that

Comment: ..check with checkpoints in `onOptionsItemSelected` which ID  you actually receive and in your `R`-file, to which its related. otherwise a `CLEAN project` may resolve this, because it looks fine